# Simple row layout using Autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've a simple layout that I know how to do it with a horizontal stackview. But for learning purpouses I want to know if it is posible to code using AutoLayout constraints.

The layout is simple, it's a rectangular row that contains an image and a label.
The problem is that the label can have multiple lines and be bigger than the icon.

The desired layout is that image and label had to be centered in Y axis and the bigger height one have a margin of 8 points at top/bottom.

[image: Layout[1]]
[image]

Comment: What I have understood from your question, set you label's top and bottom constraint and set their priority 800 from 1000 and set the relation `Greater Than or Equal`. Do the same for width constraint of you label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give the image and the label a margin constraint for both top and bottom. Use *greater or equal* as relation for these margin constraints.

Comment: It worked. I combined  two Vertically center in container constraints with the >= constraints you sugest.

Answer (score 0):

First Write this in viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

Set `numberOfLine` property to `0` in `StoryBoard`

Set `UIImageView` `Constrains` like:

Fixed `Height` and `Width` and Vertical `Center` in Container.

Set `UILable` `Constrains` to `HorozontalSpacing` from `UIImageView` `Trailing Top Bottom` from `SuperView` i.e Cell.

Hope it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Give a top and bottom margin constraint for image and label. Set high priority with relation Greater Than or Equal.